# Cell complex of torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a plane model for torus. We want to decompose the plane model of torus into cell complex which satisfies

1)every face of the cell complex has exactly 6 boundary edges
2)at each vertex, there are 3 faces meet at it.

How to draw such cell complex? I have try to squeeze a set of hexagons which intersect each other along side, but I can't manage to put this set into plane model of torus to satisfy the conditions above.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a picture of such a cellulation of the torus. Identify opposite edges of the hexagon as in Daniel Rust's answer.

[image]

Comment: But midpoints do not meet at three faces. They only meet at two faces.

Comment: @Idonknow: No they meet at three. Look at the bottom midpoint. It is the same as the top one. It meets all three visible hexagons.

Comment: are you using hexagon as plane model for torus? If so, then how you define the orientation of sides of hexagon? Because I can't seem to define an orientation such that it will become a square plane model of torus.

Comment: Yes, I am using the hexagon plane model. As you go around the hexagon you have identifications $abca^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$. This is different than the square plane model which has identifications $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. You can prove that the hexagon is a model for the torus by first gluing top an bottom. Then you have a cylinder with two edges on each boundary circle. These are then glued together to give a torus.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm not sure what you mean by 'decompose a plane model for a torus' so I'll just outline how to give a CW-complex construction of a torus which satisfies your conditions.*

A hexagon with side edge pairings $[abca^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}]$ is homeomorphic to the torus (seen by cutting along the line from the center of one $a$ edge to the center of the other $a$ edge and then gluing along the $c$ edges). This doesn't yet satisfy your first condition because the face only has three boundary edges. We can consider a union of fundamental regions though which *does* satisfy the conditions.

I drew the region in paint shown below, but the side pairing sequence is given as (the letters used refer to the colours in the image e.g $r=\color{red}{red}$, $m=\color{purple}{mauve}$, $p=\color{pink}{pink}$, ...) $$[gbpmyrb^{-1}g^{-1}m^{-1}p^{-1}r^{-1}y^{-1}]$$ which uses three of the above hexagons glued together to give a different fundamental region of a free/transitive $\mathbb{Z}^2$-action on the plane. This better satisfies the conditions you ask for because each vertex shares three *different* faces, and we have that each face properly has three boundary edges.

[image]

Comment: This example is now identical to my example!

Comment: In your original example each face only had 3 edges as boundary as well. Now they all have 6.

Comment: Ah that's true, I see hexagon and count 6. My mistake.

Comment: It's all good..

Answer (score 1):

Draw (or find on the net) a honeycomb pattern of hexagons.  Find four hexagons whose centres lie on the corners of a parallelogram.  Draw in the edges of the parallelogram,  Warp the parallelogram so it becomes a square.